# Getting Error while building React Native project

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting following error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* Where:
Settings file 'G:\ReactNative\Contacts\android\settings.gradle' line: 3

    * What went wrong:
    Could not compile settings file 'G:\ReactNative\Contacts\android\settings.gradle'.
    > startup failed:
      settings file 'G:\ReactNative\Contacts\android\settings.gradle': 3: unexpected char: '\' @ line 3, column 133.
         s\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
```

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Contacts'
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android')

include ':app'
```

What is actually wrong with this file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try forward slashes / instead of backslash \

**use code**

```
rootProject.name = 'Contacts'
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')

include ':app'
```

**instead of**

```
rootProject.name = 'Contacts'
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '..\node_modules\react-native-vector-icons\android')

include ':app'
```

Hope it will help

Comment: hey can you help me with this error ?   **Build failed with an exception Could not Compile Settings File ‘project/android/settings.gradle’.**

Comment: `rootProject.name = 'PortalAPP'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
`                      **here is my code**